# "has no member" error with Alamofire 4.0 with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I have used Alamofire 4.0 in with Swift 3.0 but getting issue with the following code

> Type 'Method' (aka 'OpaquePointer') has no member 'GET'
>
> Type 'Method' (aka 'OpaquePointer') has no member 'PUT'
>
> Type 'Method' (aka 'OpaquePointer') has no member 'POST'
>
> Type 'Method' (aka 'OpaquePointer') has no member 'PATCH'
>
> Type 'Method' (aka 'OpaquePointer') has no member 'DELETE'

Enum definition:

```
enum Method {
        case get
        case put
        case post
        case patch
        case delete

        func toAFMethod() -> Alamofire.Method {
            switch self {
            case .get:
                return Alamofire.Method.GET
            case .put:
                return Alamofire.Method.PUT
            case .post:
                return Alamofire.Method.POST
            case .patch:
                return Alamofire.Method.PATCH
            case .delete:
                return Alamofire.Method.DELETE
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try `Alamofire.HTTPMethod.get`, etc. -- HTTPMethod and lowercase verb https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#http-methods.

Comment: ... and these are now `.get`, `.put`, etc., in lowercase.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on Swift 3 and Alamofire 4.0 there is major change in API :

```
import Alamofire

enum Method {
    case get
    case put
    case post
    case patch
    case delete

    func toAFMethod() -> Alamofire.HTTPMethod {
        switch self {
        case .get:
            return Alamofire.HTTPMethod.get
        case .put:
            return Alamofire.HTTPMethod.put
        case .post:
            return Alamofire.HTTPMethod.post
        case .patch:
            return Alamofire.HTTPMethod.patch
        case .delete:
            return Alamofire.HTTPMethod.delete
        }
    }
}
```

[Check Alamofire 4.0 Migration Guide For More Information.](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md)

Hope this will help you.